# Why we use @ForeignKey(name="FK_COUNTRY") annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I have been going through some relational stuff in hibernate where I get this solution for relation between tables I tried this it works fine but when I remove **@ForeignKey(name="FK_COUNTRY")** nothing change then why are we using this annotation is that came under best practice?

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "state")
    public class State {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne
        @ForeignKey(name="FK_COUNTRY")
        private Country country;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the javadoc of [`@ForeignKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html), you'll find:

> Used to specify the handling of foreign key constraints **when schema generation is in effect**. If this annotation is not specified, the persistence provider's default foreign key strategy will be used.

If you don't generate the database schema from the class definitions (e.g. `CREATE TABLE` SQL statement), then the annotation has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate should reflect DB structure,
You should read about the [importance of foreign key](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/importance-foreign-key-constraint-tim-miles/)

> 1. Referential Integrity
> 2. Easier Detective Work
> 3. Better performance

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems your referred doc states the importance according to db

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan hibernate should reflect DB structure